# VisualSFM install mac issue

Tags: sift

Installing [VisualSFM](http://ccwu.me/vsfm/) on mac with the [Dan Monaghan installer](https://github.com/luckybulldozer/VisualSFM_OS_X_Installer) and halfway through the build I get an error that reads:

> libsiftgpu.so failed to build. Halting.

What caused this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling found many with similar issues, was able to combine pieces from different solutions and get it working.

---

> **Why the error occurs:**

The program tries to build & install a **siftgpu** function on line 246 of the **vsfm_os_x_installer.sh** file. 

*But that link is dead.*

---

**Step 1:**
Manually insert a **[sift_gpu.zip](https://github.com/pitzer/SiftGPU)** file into your `/users/USERNAME/` directory.

---

**Step 2:**
After the sift_gpu.zip file is in your users/USERNAME directory, [Ninorian](https://github.com/luckybulldozer/VisualSFM_OS_X_Installer/issues/44#issuecomment-327797039) changed the following lines *(in the vsfm_os_x_installer.sh file)* and it worked for me too:

> Search for :  sed -i '' 
> Replace with: sed -i

---

**Step 3:**
The **sift_gpu.zip** file opens a directory called **SiftGPU-master**, and we need to change the name to **SiftGPU**, so add this line above line 262 like this:

> *(line 261)* mv SiftGPU-master SiftGPU
>   
>   *(line 262)* cd SiftGPU

---

**Step 4:**
I got this far, but kept getting errors that said “file or directory not found”, and this was remedied by changing the file extension on **line 356** in the vsfm_os_x_installer.sh file* (hat-tip to this [Github build issue support ticket](https://github.com/luckybulldozer/VisualSFM_OS_X_Installer/issues/33#issuecomment-230934224))

**From this:**

> cp ../patches/SparseBundleCPU.patch src/pba/

**To this:**

> cp -R  /users/USERNAME/downloads/VisualSFM_OS_X_Installer-master/patches/SparseBundleCPU.patch src/pba

---

After that, everything finished installing smoothly, 
But I couldn't run it yet.

---

**Step 5:**

*This 5-minute [VisualSFM Mac install](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lxAELAB4xmU) YouTube tutorial helped.* 
Here are the steps:

- You need to add 2 scripts to your `~/.bash_profile`, go into terminal and type: `nano ~/.bash_profile` and then paste those two scripts at the bottom of that file.
- Save and close `~/.bash_profile`
- Then go into the `/users/USERNAME/vsfm/bin` folder and copy `libpa.so` **AND** `libsiftgpu.so` and paste them into your /users/USERNAME/ directory.
- Create a new folder in `/users/vsfm` directory called `/users/vsfm/sift`
- Move the `SiftGPU` folder from your `users/USERNAME/` directory into your `/users/vsfm/sift` directory

---

From there, go to `users/USERNAME/vsfm/bin/` and double-click on VisualSFM, and if all went well the program should start running and open up, ready for use.

This was a pain in the ass to troubleshoot but it's over and done and I hope this helps anybody.